# updating data regularly from a website shiny

Tags: r, shiny, auto-update

I have a shiny app using data from different websites, and all these data are monthly. They are updated at different times by the website handlers. I was directly reading the data from the website in my app initially, but one of the sites went into maintenance for 2 days and I could not run my app. I don't want that situation to happen again. So I thought of saving data in my local files so that code will run.

Since the data needs to be updated to the latest available values, I want help with scheduling. I want this code to run once a month so that my data will always be up to date.

```
dMean <- function(d){
                  dd <- d  %>% filter(!between(month, 4, 10)) %>%
                    arrange(Year, month) %>%
                    filter(!(Year == min(Year) & month %in% 1:3 | 
                               Year == max(Year) & month %in% 11:12)) %>%
                    group_by(grp = cumsum(month == 11)) %>%
                    summarise(Year = last(Year),
                              value = mean(value)) %>%
                    select(-grp)
                  return(dd)
               }
    
dG1 <- fread('https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/time_series/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg.txt',
             header = FALSE,select = c(1:2))
GTA1 <- as.matrix(dG1)
saveRDS(GTA1,"GTA.rds")

dM1 <- fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/mei.data',header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
dM2 <- dM1[complete.cases(replace(dM1, dM1 == -999.000, NA)),]
dM3 <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(dM2)),nrow=nrow(dM2))
dM4 <- data.frame(Year = rep(unique(dM3[,1]), each = 12),month = 1:12,value = as.vector(t(dM3[,2:13])))
MEI1 <- as.matrix(dMean(dM4))
saveRDS(MEI1,"MEI.rds")

dS1 <- fread('https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices',header = TRUE,select = c(1,2,10))
dS2 <- as.matrix(dS1)
dS3 <- data.frame(Year = dS2[,1],month = dS2[,2], value = dS2[,3])
SST1 <- as.matrix(dMean(dS3))
saveRDS(SST1,"SST.rds")
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you want your shinyApp to periodically save data and read it under certain circunstances, or do you want to use a script outside your app to save data and then you want to know how can your shinyapp read it?

Comment: I want my shiny app to read data from these sites every month say 1st day and save and replace the old data file. So the data will always be up to date for further processing. I want help with scheduling. I want the code I provided here to run once every month.

Comment: By your comment, I assume your problem resides outside the app. You want to find a way to run an R script in a specific schedule, which is determined by your OS (or you could run this script in a container).
Then, on your shiny App you can put the data-reading part in a tryCatach: if it fails trying to read from web, resort to reading from disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your script in a linux-based operating system, then you can run it regularly using a crontab command. A crontab command executes applications in a scheduled manner as user defined, from hourly to monthly. Please read the manual of linux crontab command like following:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux

For example, a job running an R script every 1st of the month would be written:

0 0 1 * * Rscript userfile.R

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The requirement for this as you mentioned is a Linux-based operating system. So is this the only option to do this problem? I am on my work computer changing operating system is maybe not possible.

Comment: I use Ubuntu. I don't know what about any other operating systems. However, I believe other operating systems have also equivalent functionality to crontab as in Ubuntu.

Comment: Have a look at `taskscheduleR` package for windows equivalent of crontab. You even have an rstudio addin to configure your task.

Comment: I will check out `tasksheduleR`. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of `tasksheduleR`. I tried it with a small code it works. Just what I was looking for.